# XBee ADC without transmitting

Tags: adc, xbee

I'm trying to store data from an analog sensor using an openLog board. I'd like for the openLog to transmit its data using an XBee, should another XBee come into range.

I'd love to be able to do this without an additional microcontroller, by using the ADC in the XBee to convert the analog signal into a serial out that the openLog will store. It needs to be able to do this without transmitting at the same time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I'm a total novice at this sort of thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not seen a function that can do that in the standard Xbee firmware. I'm sure it could be done if you could develop and download custom firmware to the Xbee, but that's not something that is open to hobbyists AFAICT.

That being said, a small MCU with an ADC and a serial port of some sort will cost you maybe a dollar or two, and needs just the supply voltage and a decoupling capacitor for support. The Atmel ATTiny85 comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like this is the way forward - Mr Faludi confirmed as much https://twitter.com/faludi/status/362761331021053952